# Creating a color mixer showing the result of two combined colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a color mixer where there are 6 colors. When you click on 2 of them it shows the color that it would be if you took mixed two colors of paint and put them together.

I am wondering how to make it so that when you click two things it shows an output.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Color Mixer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greendiv"></div>
    <div id="bluediv"></div>
    <div id="yellowdiv"></div>
    <div id="reddiv"></div>
    <div id="purplediv"></div>
    <div id="orangediv"></div>
    <p id="separator">------------------------------------------
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
#greendiv {
  background-color:green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
    margin-left: 360px;
}
#bluediv {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
#yellowdiv {
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
#reddiv {
  background-color: #E42217;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -200px
}
#purplediv {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 480px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

#orangediv {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
#separator {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #565051;
  margin-top: -15px
}

#reddiv:hover {
background-color: #C11B17
}
```

Comment: please create a fiddle for it, it will help the answerers. `http://jsfiddle.net/`

Comment: working on it thanks heres the fiddle im working on: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/X4Qgf/1/

Comment: Do you have a formula for calculating how paints mix?

Comment: as @MattEllen says, If you have a formula pls post it and i'll update answer..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery XColor to do the color mixing..

See this fiddle: **choose 2 items and hit "Get Mix" button**
http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/X4Qgf/6/

```
function getMix() {
  var colors = $('.selected');
  var col1 = rgb2hex($(colors[0]).css('background-color'));
  var col2 = rgb2hex($(colors[1]).css('background-color'));
  console.log(colors);
  var additiveColor = ($.xcolor.average(col1, col2).getHex());
  console.log(col1 + ' AND ' + col2);
  console.log(' = ' + additiveColor);
  $('#result').css('background-color', additiveColor);
}
```

for this line:

```
var additiveColor = ($.xcolor.average(col1, col2).getHex());
```

you can use a number of different color calculations by changing `.average(` to whatever you want documented here: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/ (i.e. additive, subtractive.. etc)

Is this what you're after??

Answer (score 0):

Try this: First add 3 more entries to your CSS

```
#color1div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#color2div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

#resultdiv {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 240px;
}
```

Then, modify your html page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Color Mixer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var nextColor = 'color1div';
      function selectColor(colorName)
      {
        //select color
        document.getElementById(nextColor).style.backgroundColor=colorName;
        //toggle color 1 and color 2
        if(nextColor == 'color1div')
          nextColor = 'color2div';
        else
          nextColor = 'color1div';
        //mix the colors
        var color1 = document.getElementById('color1div').style.backgroundColor;
        var color2 = document.getElementById('color2div').style.backgroundColor;
        //insert your color mixing formula here and set result
        //example:
        //var result = mix(color1, color2);
        //document.getElementById('resultdiv').style.backgroundColor = result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greendiv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('green')"></div>
    <div id="bluediv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('blue')"></div>
    <div id="yellowdiv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('yellow')"></div>
    <div id="reddiv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('red')"></div>
    <div id="purplediv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('purple')"></div>
    <div id="orangediv" onclick="javascript:selectColor('orange')"></div>
    <p id="separator">------------------------------------------
    <div id="color1div"/>
    <div id="color2div"/>
    <div id="resultdiv"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click the color divs, it calls the javscript function to save the selected color in a variable. Now, you can just insert your color mixing formula and set the resulting color on the resultdiv.